# Java 2D array problem

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I want to assign some value in a 2D array.

I have 2 attributes called product and price.

```
iPad 999.9
iPod 123.4
iPhone 432.1
```

In 1-D array, I know how to assign the product value.

```
   String[] product = {"iPad", "iPod", "iPhone"};
```

However, in 2D array, if I assign like this:

```
String[][] array = new String[3][1];
array[0][1] = "iPad";
```

How can I assign the float number into the array?

Also, I have a question for sorting.

Since I declare the type of 2D array as String.

Can I sort the float price using this array?

Or I need to declare another array to do the sorting?
Thank

Answer (score 8):

You will save yourself lots of trouble, if you use objects instead of arrays to store products. E.g.,

```
class Product {
    String name;
    double price;
}
```

(add access modifiers, setters/getters and constructors if necessary)

Now you can access array of products easily without type conversions.

```
Product[] array = new Product[3];
array[0] = new Product();
array[0].name = "iPad";
array[0].price = 123.4;
```

Or, if you add constructor,

```
    Product[] array = {
        new Product("iPad", 123.4),
        new Product("iPod", 234.5),
        new Product("iPhone", 345.6)
    };
```

To allow sorting, you can implement `Comparable` interface and then call `Arrays.sort(myProductArray)`:

```
class Product implements Comparable<Product> {
    String name;
    double price;

    public int compareTo(Product p) {
        return ((Double) price).compareTo(p.price);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking advantage of generics and making Product extend Comparable<Product>.